# How to select a subset of a PostGIS table when using the QGIS Offline Editing plugin?

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing, database, offline

When using the Offline Editing plugin to 'Convert to an offline project' is it possible to make a selection of the dataset rather than 'offline' the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking this question I discovered that...after connecting to the PostGIS database and selecting the table to add into the project, press 'Set Filter'. A new window opens up where you can select what subset of the data you wish to bring into the project.